# STL vector c++ pointer iterator range based for loop raw pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, for-loop, vector, stl

When I run this code it works sometimes and after a few clicks on the HUD I get a access violation.

(I'm using Visual Studio 2015)

Where hud is 0xfff50000 (not a valid pointer, maybe iterator?)

HUD::Elements is a static std::vector

HUDs are created like this.

```
HUD *ent = new HUD;
ent->script_ptr = duk_require_heapptr(ctx, -1);
HUD::Elements.push_back(ent);

//for (int i = 0; i < HUD::Elements.size(); i++) {
    //auto hud = HUD::Elements.at(i);
//above code works fine without any exceptions
//hud or either *hud both crash
for(auto hud : HUD::Elements) {
    if (hud->script_ptr == nullptr)
        continue;
//handle onclick code here
```

Could anyone explain why this crashes and if there's a way to use the range based for loop still? Without having to use the

`for(int i = 0; i < HUD::Elements.size(); i++)` and `HUD *hud = HUD::Elements.at(i)`

Comment: provide a complete but minimal example. voted to close as lacking example.

Comment: Educated guess: something in `handle onclick code here` part modifies `HUD::Elements` right while it's being iterated over.